# How to bake normals with rounded edges

Tags: baking, normal-map

I know there are already many articles about baking normalmaps. But since Iam trying and reading for several days, I decided to ask...
Here is a video about baking normal maps for rounded edges:
https://www.artstation.com/learning/courses/NmX/intro-to-blender-2-8-for-game-art/chapters/5Rn/rounded-edge-shader

I want the cube with normalmap to looks exactly like that one with bevel mod. But I can not make it work, maybe somebody knows the solution?!
[image]

Comment: The link you added is for a paid course. So we cannot see it and don't know what is the desired appearance. The cube looks ok. If you make it darker you should see the round edges from the normal map. But the silhouette stays a cube with sharp corners because that's the low-poly geometry.

Comment: The course I referenced is free. I want the cube with normalmap to looks exactly like that one with bevel mod.

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt you can't make it look exactly the same, normal maps only changes the shading, they don't change the geometry of your mesh so the silhouette of the cube won't never look exactly the same.

Comment: In the video, it looks real great, btw I understand a normal map, it changes the reflection of light and therefore the surface changes its shape.

Comment: There's your mistake, just like the others already said: The surface **won't** change its shape.

If you want to alter the geometry of a mesh then you need to alter its geometry. Normal maps only change how the light interacts with the surface -- the shading. They're not shape-altering maps. Displacement maps are the ones that alter surfaces, but that's a different can of worms.

Plus on drastically different areas -- like corners vs curve -- this normal map shading won't look perfect anyway. You've got to read more on normal maps if you're still convinced they can alter shapes.

Comment: okay, I used wrong vocabular, shape means view. Btw. did you watch the video?